# How to find all tutorials for Mathematica?

Tags: documentation

Where can I find a central location to easily access all of Mathematica's tutorials and monographs on subjects such as (this is a very small sample and not representative of the many topics out there) linear algebra, physically based rendering, keyboard input, etc.?
I decided to search Tutorial in the Documentation Center and that didn't return anything relating to a central source.
I am also wondering where to find a list of every guide, but this is not as important.
[image]

I am filing a bug report on a tutorial where it says @@@ is interpreted as Apply with the level specification {1}. This should say @@@ is interpreted as MapApply.

Comment: I don't know what a tech note is.

Comment: From the linked post '"Tech note" in 12.1 is not so much a first-class concept as it is a qualifier applied to tutorials'

Comment: [This answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/219042/4999) to the question @Rohit linked shows how to divide the tutorials into monographs, tech notes, etc. and package them into a very nice user interface.

Comment: I took a look at the linked question.

Comment: It is helpful. What happens if the question relates to the same topic?

Comment: SystemOpen[
 FileNameJoin[{SystemInformation["FrontEnd", 
     "DocumentationInformation"]["Directory"], $Language, "System", 
   "Tutorials"}]] works

Comment: Plus ça change, plus c'est la même chose...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The tutorials are located here:

```
tutorialloc = FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "Documentation", $Language, 
  "System", "Tutorials"}];
```

Open the directory:

```
SystemOpen[tutorialloc]
```

[image]

Comment: I think tutorialloc is a typo.

Comment: Which part is the typo?

Comment: I thought you meat to type tutorialdoc

Comment: I used loc for location.

Comment: Excellent!  This will be most useful.